# Ternary contours with plotly in R

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, ternary

Ternary contour plots w/ interpolation etc. are quite easily to create in [plotly with Python](https://plotly.com/python/ternary-contour/).

Though, the main functionality of ternary plots is already available for [plotly in R](https://plotly.com/r/ternary-contour/), I am missing functionalities for interpolation, etc. to create plots like below:

[image]

Of course, there are the great R packages [Ternary](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Ternary/index.html) and [ggtern](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggtern/index.html), but I am really looking for an interactive plot that is fully supported by `plotly` (e.g. to allow mouse hovering) and that can be integrated into a `Shiny` application.

Anybody, found a solution or am I missing some options in the `plotly` R-documentation?!

**Update:** Apparently, the problem is that plotly.py's figure factory is not fully supported in R (https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/1583).

Comment: Ternary's [interpolation functions](https://ms609.github.io/Ternary/articles/interpolation.html) are shiny-compatible: it's not clear from the question whether you are building a shiny app, or want a shiny app that you can put data into (and if so, what data and how)

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question accordingly. Of course the Ternary package is Shiny compatible. But as it produces a base R graphic, the plot's interactivity, like mouse hovering etc., is limited (as for all other base plots).